# Load a chaplin module synchronously

Tags: requirejs, chaplinjs

I'm trying to just load the **`event_broker module in the chaplinjs`** .
  I am able to to do by doing something like

```
require(["underscore", "chaplin"], function(_, chaplin) 
{
var eventBroker = _({}).extend(chaplin.EventBroker);
});
```

But, this is not good enough in my case. I need to be able to load the event_broker module synchronously. I know that is what require designed to do. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that is what require designed to do.

No, that's **not** what RequireJS is designed to do. (Did you forget to put "not" in there?) RequireJS is designed to load modules *asynchronously*.

I would normally suggest loading Chaplin through a `script` element because that would be synchronous but, after looking at the code of Chaplin, I see that it fails with `throw new Error('Chaplin requires Common.js or AMD modules');` if it does not detect a CommonJS or AMD environment.

[Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) can be used to load bundles of AMD modules synchronously so this *may* be an option for you.